Reference for a reformulation of the $(3x+1)$-map
This question concerns the following discrete dynamical system which is a reformuluation of the $(3x+1)$-map defined by  $T:\mathbb{N}_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_{+}:n\mapsto\begin{cases} \frac{n}{2}&\text{if}& n\equiv 0\mod 2\\\frac{3n+1}{2}&\text{if}& n\equiv 1\mod 2\end{cases}$:
The map is defined on the space of words in the alphabet with the letters $+,-,0$, but we only consider words beginning with $+$.
I am going to give a rather informal description of the transformation (in it $(a)^n$ denotes the word consisting of $n$ consecutive $a$'s, where $n$ could be zero): Given any word in the space, go through the word from left to right and replace any occurrence of $+(0)^n-$ with $0(+)^{n+1}$ and any occurrence of $+(0)^n+$ with $+(-)^{n+1}$. Likewise with the signs reversed, i.e., replace any occurrence of $-(0)^n+$ with $0(-)^{n+1}$ and any occurrence of $-(0)^n-$ with $-(+)^{n+1}$. Leave $(0)^n$ unchanged. If you reach the end of the word and there is a non-zero letter missing to finish the procedure, add a $+$ to the right of the word. Any possible $0$ at the beginning of the new word is removed.
First example:
Take $+0-++-000+00+0+-$, this word brakes down to the following blocks:
$(+0-)(++)(-000+)(00)(+0+)-$
We need to add a $+$ to the end:
$(+0-)(++)(-000+)(00)(+0+)(-+)$.
Applying the transformation gives:
$(0++)(+-)(0----)(00)(+--)(0-)$
In the end, we remove the leading $0$:
$+++-0----00+--0-$
Second example: Let's say the starting word is "$++-$". The first iterates are:
$++-\mapsto +-0-\mapsto+00-\mapsto+++\mapsto$ $+-+-\mapsto +0+\mapsto +--\mapsto +0-\mapsto ++\mapsto +-\mapsto +$.
No my question is: Is there any reference for this formulation in the  literature? My search was unsuccessful so far. As I am mentioning this in a paper I want to make sure that I am not missing anything.
Edit: Here is why this transformation is equivalent to the $(3x+1)$-map: If $w=a_n...a_0$ is a word and $f(+)=1, f(-)=-1, f(0)=0$, then via $\phi(w)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(a_k)3^k$ the transformation is conjugate to the map $T$.

Welcome to math.stackexchange. Let me suggest that you take the tour, where you will see the following quote: This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. So "sharing one's thoughts" is not really what goes on here. Did you have an actual mathematical question to ask?

Please read the question before commenting. I clearly stated the main purpose of my question and it clearly falls within the purpose of this site. If you don't have anything constructive to contribute, please refrain from commenting.

@Lee Mosher I think that this well-written question with a detailed example, in its present form, saying "has this automata been already met in the existing litterature" is perfectly acceptable for Math SE.

So you are saying it is equivalent to collatz ? Is this a 1 april joke ?

@mick feel free to check it!

I think godel esher and bach ( the book ) contains equivalent statements to collatz with MUI type systems.

@mick there are certainly many equivalent formulation of the Collatz map. My question is whether this particular one has appeared before in the literature. As far as I can judge after a brief research it doesn't appear in gödel escher bach, or do you think it does?

@dialegou not sure. But why not ask your professor or other students and researchers ?
Also i wonder why this is so interesting to you, since it is already known as collatz.

@mick You are assuming that I didn't ask elsewhere. That assumption is incorrect. As I said in the OP, I am mentioning this in an article, so it would be nice to know if this has appeared somewhere before or if it is new.
